# What is the name of the financial service that holds deposits for an exchange?

Tags: foreign-exchange, currency, regulation, money-market

I want to set up a fx currency market (the barrier is low in my region). Instead of getting a license to hold customer deposits for trading, I've been told that there are institutions that hold deposits & perform settlements (wire transfers) on my behalf.

What is the name of this service? Any examples?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about personal finance.

Comment: I can't post an answer because this question is "on hold" but it sounds like you want to find a prime broker. I had a former employer that sold a BYOB, Be Your Own Broker, program where they supplied MetaQuotes software preconfigured. Honestly, seems like a pyramid scheme. Check with your liquidity providers to see what services they offer.

Answer (score 0):

That would be called "[Escrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escrow)" services, and they are implemented using [trusts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_law) or other similar legal mechanisms. The escrow service provider can be any kind of entity (within the limits of the applicable local law, of course).

Comment: Thank you. However, I'm am not looking for an arbiter between two parties. What I need is a financial service provider to hold all of the funds of my customers. My trading platform would send it payement (wire) amounts to customers that have requested withdrawals.

Comment: @FXer you mean bank?